# C# DataGridView adding custom objects as data source

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource

I'm trying to populate a datagridview with the properties from a custom object that has a another custom object as a property.:

```
class InventoryItem
{
    public NItem Item { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
class NItem
{
    public String ItemNumber { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public double WholesalePrice { get; set; }
    public double RetailPrice { get; set; }
    public String Model { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
}
```

I want the datagridview to display each of the properties from NItem and the Quantity from Inventory Item. the code I'm using looks like this:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = idr.GetAllItems();
```

idr reads the items from a database and returns a list of InventoryItems

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:
I figured it out i used a data table and looped through the inventory producing unique columns. code:

```
        // Create a new DataTable.
        System.Data.DataTable table = new DataTable("InventoryTable");
        // Declare variables for DataColumn and DataRow objects.
        DataColumn column;
        DataRow row;

        // Create first column.
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        column.ColumnName = "ItemNumber";
        column.AutoIncrement = false;
        column.Caption = "Item Number";
        column.ReadOnly = true;
        column.Unique = true;
        // Add the column to the table.
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create second column.
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        column.ColumnName = "Title";
        column.AutoIncrement = false;
        column.Caption = "Title";
        column.ReadOnly = true;
        column.Unique = false;
        // Add the column to the table.
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create third column.
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        column.ColumnName = "Model";
        column.AutoIncrement = false;
        column.Caption = "Model";
        column.ReadOnly = false;
        column.Unique = false;
        // Add the column to the table.
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create fourth column.
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double");
        column.ColumnName = "WholesalePrice";
        column.AutoIncrement = false;
        column.Caption = "Wholesale Price";
        column.ReadOnly = false;
        column.Unique = false;
        // Add the column to the table.
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create fifth column.
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double");
        column.ColumnName = "RetailPrice";
        column.AutoIncrement = false;
        column.Caption = "Retail Price";
        column.ReadOnly = false;
        column.Unique = false;
        // Add the column to the table.
        table.Columns.Add(column);


        // Create sixth column.
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        column.ColumnName = "Quantity";
        column.AutoIncrement = false;
        column.Caption = "Quantity";
        column.ReadOnly = false;
        column.Unique = false;
        // Add the column to the table.
        table.Columns.Add(column);


        // Create seventh column.
        //column = new DataColumn();
        //column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime");
        //column.ColumnName = "DatePurchased";
        //column.AutoIncrement = false;
        //column.Caption = "Date Purchased";
        //column.ReadOnly = false;
        //column.Unique = false;
        //// Add the column to the table.
        //table.Columns.Add(column);


        // Create eigth column.
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        column.ColumnName = "URL";
        column.AutoIncrement = false;
        column.Caption = "URL";
        column.ReadOnly = false;
        column.Unique = false;
        // Add the column to the table.
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            row = table.NewRow();
            row["ItemNumber"] = item.Item.ItemNumber;
            row["Title"] = item.Item.Title;
            row["Model"] = item.Item.Model;
            row["WholesalePrice"] = item.Item.WholesalePrice;
            row["RetailPrice"] = item.Item.RetailPrice;
            row["Quantity"] = item.Quantity;
            row["URL"] = item.Item.URL;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

Comment: have  you tried creating a List<NItem> and binding it to the grid that way..? also you could bind the DataGrid to a DataSet or DataView or DataTable there are so many options you have what else have you tried and or investigated? research the following as well 
`ObjectBindingSource`

Answer (score 0):

You should try using databinding and viewmodels  and a datagrid 
Lets say that you have a view like that this in XAML

```
<UserControl
     User Control properties
     xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ProjectName.ViewModel">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <view:ClassName/>
</Userontrol.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemSource={"Binding InventoryItems"}/>

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Lets say you have an InventoryItem ViewModel

```
Public class InventoryItemViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{  

    public InventoryItemsViewModel()
    {
         PopulateInventoryItems();
    }
    public List<InventoryItem> _inventoryItems;

    private List<InventoryItem>
    { 
         get
         {
            return _inventoryItems;
         }
         set
         {
            _inventoryItems = value;
             RaiseProperyChanged();
         }
    }

    //Populate your List here

    Private PopulateInventoryItems()
    {

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }

}
```